# Java Error in VS Code - How to solve this problem - bank The type bank.Account is not visibleJava

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sOzG.png)

Why I am getting error to access the class from import file.?
Error:
bank
The type bank.Account is not visibleJava

Here I am attaching the img.

Comment: Please type your code in the question rather than an image. It makes it easier for people to answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have added both the `workspace folder` and the `src folder` into `classpath`.

But `App.java` and `Bank.java` are still in different packages. The class `Account` is not public, so you can not get it in the different packages such as `App.java`.

You can move it to another file named `Account.java`:

```
package bank;

public class Account {
    public String name;
}
```

Under the bank folder, and Add this in the `App.java`:

```
import bank.Account;
```